# How do I display future appointments in Outlook with a DASL filter

Tags: outlook-2007

I would like to customise my Outlook 2007 calendar view so that it only displays future appointments. What's the DASL syntax to say ">= "today"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the cryptic syntax for the fields.

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/820D0040" >= today(0)
```

I got that from
[an Outlook 2007 book on Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Jp8qWFtiSl0C&pg=PA507&lpg=PA507&dq=urn%3aschemas%3acalendar%3adtstart+today+dasl&source=bl&ots=hdAd9bGB8d&sig=fQKE4JD107U4-4bdpHoTKMhnvDc&hl=en&ei=VRTUTKSmINq5jAevwInKCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)